# Office.context.document.getFileAsync throwing errors

Tags: javascript, ms-office, apps-for-office

I am getting a very strange issue whereby when I try to extract the word document as a compressed file for processing in my MS Word Task Pane MVC app the third time, it will blow up.

Here is the code:

```
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, function (result) {
if (result.status == "succeeded") {
    var file = result.value;

    file.getSliceAsync(0, function (resultSlice) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    });
} else {
    //TODO: Service fault handling?
}
});
```

The error code that comes up is 5001. I am not sure how to fix this.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts on this.

Additional Details:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From MSDN:

> No more than two documents are allowed to be in memory; otherwise the
>   `getFileAsync` operation will fail. Use the `File.closeAsync` method to
>   close the file when you are finished working with it.

Make sure you call `File.closeAsync` before you read the file again - that could explain the issue you are seeing.

More at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj715284.aspx

Comment: This is pretty much what causes the 5001 error from my experiments

Answer (score 2):

I have an example about how to use this API correctly. Actually the current example in the MSDN is not very correct. This code is tested in Word.

```
// Usually we encode the data in base64 format before sending it to server.
function encodeBase64(docData) {
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < docData.length; i++)
        s += String.fromCharCode(docData[i]);
    return window.btoa(s);
}

// Call getFileAsync() to start the retrieving file process.
function getFileAsyncInternal() {
    Office.context.document.getFileAsync("compressed", { sliceSize: 10240 }, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            document.getElementById("log").textContent = JSON.stringify(asyncResult);
        }
        else {
            getAllSlices(asyncResult.value);
        }
    });
}

// Get all the slices of file from the host after "getFileAsync" is done.
function getAllSlices(file) {
    var sliceCount = file.sliceCount;
    var sliceIndex = 0;
    var docdata = [];
    var getSlice = function () {
        file.getSliceAsync(sliceIndex, function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == "succeeded") {
                docdata = docdata.concat(asyncResult.value.data);
                sliceIndex++;
                if (sliceIndex == sliceCount) {
                    file.closeAsync();
                    onGetAllSlicesSucceeded(docdata);
                }
                else {
                    getSlice();
                }
            }
            else {
                file.closeAsync();
                document.getElementById("log").textContent = JSON.stringify(asyncResult);

            }
        });
    };
    getSlice();
}

// Upload the docx file to server after obtaining all the bits from host.
function onGetAllSlicesSucceeded(docxData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Handler.ashx",
        data: encodeBase64(docxData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    }).done(function (data) {
        document.getElementById("documentXmlContent").textContent = data;
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    });
}
```

You may find more information from here: 
https://github.com/pkkj/AppForOfficeSample/tree/master/GetFileAsync

Hope this could help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @KejingPeng how can I retrieve the Word document in .docx extention?

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Keyjing Peng's answer (which I found very helpful, thanks!) I thought I'd share a variation on the encodeBase64, which you don't want to do if you are uploading via REST to SharePoint. In that case you want to convert the byte array to a Uint8Array. Only then could I get it into a SharePoint library without file corruption.

```
var uArray = new Uint8Array(docdata);
```

Hope this helps someone, couldn't find this info anywhere else online...

Answer (score -1):

See this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj715284(v=office.1501401).aspx

it contains this example method:

```
var i = 0;
var slices = 0;

function getDocumentAsPDF() {

Office.context.document.getFileAsync("pdf",{sliceSize: 2097152}, function (result) {
    if (result.status == "succeeded") {
        // If the getFileAsync call succeeded, then
        // result.value will return a valid File Object.
         myFile = result.value;
         slices = myFile.sliceCount;
         document.getElementById("result").innerText = " File size:" + myFile.size + " #Slices: " + slices;

         // Iterate over the file slices.
         for ( i = 0; i < slices; i++) {
             var slice = myFile.getSliceAsync(i, function (result) {
                 if (result.status == "succeeded") {  
                     doSomethingWithChunk(result.value.data);
                     if (slices == i) // Means it's done traversing...
                     {
                         SendFileComplete();
                     }
                 }
                 else
                     document.getElementById("result").innerText = result.error.message;
                 });
         }
         myFile.closeAsync();
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("result2").innerText = result.error.message;
});
```

}

change "pdf" to "compressed" and the method call doSomethingWithChunk() needs to be created and should probably do something like this:

```
function base64Encode(str) {
        return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function (match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
        }));
    }
```

I use this technique to successfully save to Azure blob storage.

Obviously you should rename the method as well.

Comment: This will fail on documents larger than the slice size (having multiple slices) because the `i` value is being declared outside of the `getSliceAsync` function.