# Retrieve word document from sharepoint

Tags: office-js, word-addins, word-web-addins

[image: API design]

I'm creating a Word web add-in. As it showed in the image I need to make a POST request from add-in's web app to some third party API. For this POST request I need to attach the Word document that saved in sharepoint. And I need to attach it with .docx file extention only. How can I use Office.js API `Office.context.document.getFileAsync` method to handle this scenario. Can I get the Word file with .docx extention from `getFileAsync` method ?

Comment: I wen through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27751294/7158152) answer and what I'm struggling is retrieving the file in .docx extention.